# Find the values of parameter $a$ so that....

Tags: parametric

Determine all the values of real parameter $a$ so that the equation:$$(x-a)[log_4(x-5)-1]=0$$ admits a maximum number of real solutions. 
Thank you!

Comment: Obviously the function $(x-a)$ can only have one root (which is  $a$), regardless of what the value of $a$ is, so it remains to find the the root(s) with maximum multiplicity for $\log_4(x-5)-1$

Comment: This means that the root of the second equation that's 9 is respectively the value of $a$, and in such a case we'll have a maximum number of real solutions, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But can you explain why?

Comment: Say you have functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Suppose $f(x)$ has $m$ roots and $g(x)$ has $n$ roots. What is the number of roots for the product $H(x)=f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: If $A(x) \times B(x)=0$, either $A(x)=0$ or $B(x)=0$

Comment: @fixedp m+n roots then.

Comment: Yes. Now if $f(x)=(x-a)$, we have $m=1$ regardless of what we choose for $a$. Since we want to maximise $m+n$, and $m$ is fixed, it is natural to maximise $n$. In this case, $n$ is one when $a=9$ and $n=0$ otherwise. So to maximise the number of solutions (which is $m+n$), we need to have $a=9$.

Comment: @fixedp Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-a)(\log_4(x-5)-1)=0\\(x-a)=0\lor \log_4(x-5)=1\\x=a\lor x=9$$
Now if $a\not= 9$ then solutions are $x_1=a,x_2=9$,so maximum number of solutions is for $a\not=9$